# CSS not applying in Firefox, Chrome/IE is fine

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

I am trying to get the #contact section (First Name, Surname, Position, Company) as well as the search text on the left hidden nav to change from black to white.

I've added the CSS in (multiple locations) however the colors are still not changing in Firefox. Could anyone check it over and tell me what might be happening as I am fairly lost.

http://biolineapp.com/#contact

Comment: please post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fbiolineapp.com%2F%23contact

Answer (score 3):

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
```